# Malformed: Limit quality is not allowed for XRP to XRP

Tags: xrp

I use the common line :

```
rippled submit_multisigned '{"TransactionType":"Payment","Account":"rBFiSRP7asY6CajpRpSdqmoRbN3FAebpNv","Destination":"raNrt34FdELxDGfBCR46euASUdcoNEaf9K","DestinationTag":"025465","Amount":"1000000","Sequence":1,"SigningPubKey":"","Fee":"30000","Flags":262144,"Signers":[{"Signer":{"Account":"rhTqqVzJojgTuPAQ9oti3SRcFcsNRcqqgM","SigningPubKey":"024EDC40BC022FE0324F5244939C66E24988DE141BE738DAC25F6A51FD6D0EED5D","TxnSignature":"**"}},{"Signer":{"Account":"rD9KVojocpjsZcisDMTaKiTm2Kg2HevLqF","SigningPubKey":"035A908008D533C2E25CF9823144A026DA7FBE094588EB312862D14CEECF7F60BA","TxnSignature":"**"}}],"hash":"2D9852A4F44F1E979B40EEEF401932C1D8CF852A9F8EDC3C079E211DE6C244B3"}'
```

And got the result like that

```
{
   "result" : {
      "engine_result" : "temBAD_SEND_XRP_LIMIT",
      "engine_result_code" : -289,
      "engine_result_message" : "Malformed: Limit quality is not allowed for XRP to XRP.",
      "status" : "success",
      "tx_blob" : "****",
      "tx_json" : {
         "Account" : "rBFiSRP7asY6CajpRpSdqmoRbN3FAebpNv",
         "Amount" : "1000000",
         "Destination" : "raNrt34FdELxDGfBCR46euASUdcoNEaf9K",
         "DestinationTag" : 25465,
         "Fee" : "30000",
         "Flags" : 262144,
         "Sequence" : 1,
         "Signers" : [
            {
               "Signer" : {
                  "Account" : "rhTqqVzJojgTuPAQ9oti3SRcFcsNRcqqgM",
                  "SigningPubKey" : "024EDC40BC022FE0324F5244939C66E24988DE141BE738DAC25F6A51FD6D0EED5D",
                  "TxnSignature" : "****"
               }
            },
            {
               "Signer" : {
                  "Account" : "rD9KVojocpjsZcisDMTaKiTm2Kg2HevLqF",
                  "SigningPubKey" : "035A908008D533C2E25CF9823144A026DA7FBE094588EB312862D14CEECF7F60BA",
                  "TxnSignature" : "***"
               }
            }
         ],
         "SigningPubKey" : "",
         "TransactionType" : "Payment",
         "hash" : "2CEB1FFF2CDF723D80BEA4357E3445223FDBBD9245901240E4BF05CE42688DD1"
      }
   }
}
```

The error is :Malformed: Limit quality is not allowed for XRP to XRP.
In the official website api has been found and did not find how to solve。
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Sry, it should be the paramters add "Flags" : 262144